# Hive queries taking so long

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

I have a CDP environment running Hive, for some reason some queries run pretty quickly and others are taking even more than 5 minutes to run, even a regular select current_timestamp or things like that.
I see that my cluster usage is pretty low so I don't understand why this is happening.

How can I use my cluster fully? I read some posts in the cloudera website, but they are not helping a lot, after all the tuning all the things are the same.

Something to note is that I have the following message in the hive logs:

```
"Get Query Coordinator (AM)  350"
```

Then I see that the time to execute the query was pretty low.

I am using tez, any idea what can I look at?

Comment: Hi, did you change any defaults? or you are running on default, especially on the yarn side?

Comment: I just took the CDP environment, I tuned everything that I could with this : https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Demystify-Apache-Tez-Memory-Tuning-Step-by-Step/ta-p/245279 but even after that everything seems the same.

Comment: Are you setting up any queues with tez.queue.name when running queries? is your yarn default queues set up?

Comment: Not really, nothing like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides taking care of the overall tuning: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Demystify-Apache-Tez-Memory-Tuning-Step-by-Step/ta-p/245279

Please check my answer to this same issue here [Enable hive parallel processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473933/apache-tez-tasks-on-hold-at-the-application-master)

That post explains what you need to do to enable parallel processing.

Comment: Let me check it and come back

Comment: It is amazing the documentation doesn't clearly states that, I added 2 queues, put them as default and by using tez.queue.name I am able to use all my queries now, they get processed pretty quickly, thanks man, you literally saved my life